# Struggling with GET from API in PHP

Tags: php, rest

I am wondering if anyone could help me with an API GET in PHP?

I play ETS2 and use the API from Truckers MP which is fine but I am wanting to pull information from the Telemetry Server APP while playing the game and output to my site.

The API in question is https://github.com/Funbit/ets2-telemetry-server

I currently have this code:

```
$json = file_get_contents('http://iltelemetry.inet-developments.org:25555/api/ets2/telemetry');
$data = json_decode($json);
            
foreach($data->game as $conn){
}
$conn = $game->connected;
if ($conn == 'true'){
    echo 'Connected to telemetry';
}
else{
    echo 'Not Connected to telemetry';
}
$conn = $data->response->connected;
$game = $data->response->gameName;
echo'<li id="fleet" >';
echo '<center>Connected: '. $conn . '<p></center>';
echo '<center>Game Name: '. $game . '<p></center>';
echo'</li>';
```

I may be doing something totally wrong here and I accept that, but when ran I am just getting not connected. For example, I am trying to learn about API's and JAVA.

Any help would be appreciated.

Different code usage and following examples along with Google searches.

Comment: your code makes no sense, by itself, and when evaluated against the json at the url you gave.  1 `foreach` does nothing; 2 `$game` is not defined 3 `$data` has no response property, 4 there seems to be a single game object in the data (why foreach?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code works with the data at the server.

```
    $json = file_get_contents('http://iltelemetry.inet-developments.org:25555/api/ets2/telemetry');
    $data = json_decode($json);
    $game = $data->game;
    if($game) {
        $conn = $game->connected ? "Connected" : "Not connected";
        $name = $game->gameName;
        echo '<li id="fleet" >';
        echo '<center>Connected: ' . $conn . '<p></center>';
        echo '<center>Game Name: ' . $name . '<p></center>';
        echo '</li>';
    } else {
        // any error recovery here
        echo 'Did not get a game object from server '; 
    }
```

I took the liberty of removing an echo , possibly some prior debug'ish attempt.  Before writing code, look at the data.  If you dont have a proper IDE , you could paste the json at `jsonlint.com` ,

- validate the JSON. If not valid JSON, try to get the API provider to fix their system.
- When valid, observe the structure of the data.  The structure of you code will almost every time be the same.

Comment: Thank you so much greatly appreciated working as i was trying to get it to